# sql query hour timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have created a query with Where clause for a particular date as Run date

```
WHERE TRUNC(CHANGE_DATE) = to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I want this should give from only `0000` hours to `1500` hours data.

`CHANGE_DATE` is the column name which has date in the format "`10/7/2016  10:01:51 PM`"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are saying you want only change dates in the range from 00:00 to 15:00 ? If so than just add:

```
WHERE TRUNC(CHANGE_DATE) = to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR(CHANGE_DATE,'HH24') <=15
```

(I am assuming Oracle DB).